# Delete cookie on clicking sign out

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am creating the cookie using the code below, How to read the txtusername value in another page and how to delete the cookie when I click sign out(code for sign out). I am new to programming please help.

```
  string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;
            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.Value, DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "your custom data");
            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);

            ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
            if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
                ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration;
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

Comment: You really shouldn't replace your entire code just like that. It's not the same question as it was 11 minutes ago

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should never store *password* as a *cookie*. That's a very big security threat.  To delete a cookie, you really just need to modify and expire it.  You can't really delete it, i.e. remove it from the user's disk. Check out this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx).

Here is a sample:

```
 HttpCookie aCookie;
    string cookieName;
    int limit = Request.Cookies.Count;
    for (int i=0; i<limit; i++)
    {
        cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
        aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); // make it expire yesterday
        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie); // overwrite it
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot directly delete a cookie, you have to set it to expire before the current date:

```
if (Request.Cookies["clienDetails"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("clienDetails");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx).

Furthermore I really encourage you to not write your own security but to read up on [asp.net membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx). More secure and easier to use. As I can see many flaws in your security model. Storing the password in plain text in a cookie is really really bad.

**EDIT:**
As you now changed your code, you have to do this to remove the cookie:

```
if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how to read the txtusername value.the below code worked when i stored the password and email id without encrypting  if(Request.Cookies["Cookiename"] != null)
        {
            Label8.Text = Request.Cookies["cookiename"].Values["client_ID"].ToString();
            
        }

Comment: @Gokul Try User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 1):

In my case this code worked:

```
Response.Cookies.Delete("access_token");
return Ok();
```

Comment: This worked for me in .Net 7 Razor pages. Seems they finally added a simple method.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this did not work for me using `Chrome 69` with the `Continue where you left off` feature enabled. Similar issue with Firefox.  Disabling this feature worked for me.

See

- [Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772420/885535)
- [How to delete or expire a cookie in Chrome using Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462951/how-to-delete-or-expire-cookie-in-chrome-using-asp-net)