# Decrypting Chromium cookies

Tags: python, c++, google-chrome, cookies, chromium

I'm trying to use Chromium cookies in Python, because Chromium encrypts its cookies using AES (with CBC) I need to reverse this.

I can recover the AES key from OS X's Keychain (it's stored in Base 64):

```
security find-generic-password -w -a Chrome -s Chrome Safe Storage
# From Python:
python -c 'from subprocess import PIPE, Popen; print(Popen(['security', 'find-generic-password', '-w', '-a', 'Chrome', '-s', 'Chrome Safe Storage'], stdout=PIPE).stdout.read().strip())'
```

Here's the code I have, all I'm missing is decrypting the cookies:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from sqlite3 import dbapi2

def get_encryption_key():
  cmd = ['security', 'find-generic-password', '-w', '-a', 'Chrome', '-s', 'Chrome Safe Storage']
  return Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read().strip().decode('base-64')

def get_cookies(database):
  key = get_encryption_key()
  with dbapi2.connect(database) as conn:
    conn.rollback()
    rows = conn.cursor().execute('SELECT name, encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE host_key like ".example.com"')

  cookies = {}
  for name, enc_val in rows:
    val = decrypt(enc_val, key) # magic missing
    cookies[name] = val

  return cookies
```

I tried a bunch of things with [pyCrypto's AES module](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html) but:

1. I have no Initialization Vector (IV)
2. `enc_val` is not a multiple of 16 in length

Here are some links that seem useful:

- [the commit that started it all](https://codereview.chromium.org/24734007)
- [components/encryptor/keychain_password_mac.mm](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/components/encryptor/keychain_password_mac.mm?pathrev=257572)
- [AES key generation (not used in OS X but could help someone else)](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/crypto/symmetric_key.h?revision=260152#l43)
- [cookie insertion function](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/content/browser/net/sqlite_persistent_cookie_store.cc#l996)

Can you help me figure this out?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're on the right track! I've been working on this for a few days and finally figured it out. (Many thanks to the OP for the helpful links to the Chromium source.)

I've put up a [post](http://n8henrie.com/2014/05/decrypt-chrome-cookies-with-python/) with a little more detail and a working script, but here is the basic idea:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2

# Function to get rid of padding
def clean(x): 
    return x[:-x[-1]].decode('utf8')

# replace with your encrypted_value from sqlite3
encrypted_value = ENCRYPTED_VALUE 

# Trim off the 'v10' that Chrome/ium prepends
encrypted_value = encrypted_value[3:]

# Default values used by both Chrome and Chromium in OSX and Linux
salt = b'saltysalt'
iv = b' ' * 16
length = 16

# On Mac, replace MY_PASS with your password from Keychain
# On Linux, replace MY_PASS with 'peanuts'
my_pass = MY_PASS
my_pass = my_pass.encode('utf8')

# 1003 on Mac, 1 on Linux
iterations = 1003

key = PBKDF2(my_pass, salt, length, iterations)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_value)
print(clean(decrypted))
```

Comment: Awesome! I only rewrote clean to work with Python 2: `def clean(x): return x[:-ord(x[-1])]` ([PEP8 says no f = lambda](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) ;) )

Comment: Sweet. Edited to reflect this.

Comment: How can I install the imported packages?

Comment: pip install pycrypto I think, but I've also bundled all this up into a package called pycookiecheat that now uses the `cryptography` package

Comment: Hi, few months ago this script's worked flawlessly, but today the return x[:-x[-1]].decode('utf8') not works, it gives back empty entry (the -x part exactly)

Comment: @osiixy have you tried the package I made based on the above? https://github.com/n8henrie/pycookiecheat

Answer (score 5):

[@n8henrie's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23727331/296069) answer worked for me, but in my environment with Ubuntu, Chrome no longer use 'peanuts' as password, instead it's stored in gnome keyring. I managed to get the password for decryption using [secretstorage](https://secretstorage.readthedocs.io/) package like this:

```
import secretstorage

bus = secretstorage.dbus_init()
collection = secretstorage.get_default_collection(bus)
for item in collection.get_all_items():
    if item.get_label() == 'Chrome Safe Storage':
        MY_PASS = item.get_secret()
        break
else:
    raise Exception('Chrome password not found!')
```

Comment: Correct -- if anyone is interested, this Ubuntu / Gnome keyring issue has been discussed a little bit [in this issue](https://github.com/n8henrie/pycookiecheat/issues/12) in my package pycookiecheat, which implemented a similar solution as a result.