# Chrome 80 how to decode cookies

Tags: python, google-chrome, cookies, aes, dpapi

I had a working script for opening and decrypting Google Chrome cookies which looked like:

```
decrypted = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(enctypted_cookie_value, None, None, None, 0)
```

It seems that after update 80 it is no longer a valid solution.

According to this blog post https://blog.nirsoft.net/2020/02/19/tools-update-new-encryption-chrome-chromium-version-80/ it seems that i need to CryptUnprotectData on encrypted_key from Local State file, than somehow decrypt cookie, using decrypted key.

For the first part i got my encrypted_key

```
path = r'%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State'
path = os.path.expandvars(path)
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    encrypted_key = json.loads(file.read())['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']
encrypted_key = bytearray(encrypted_key, 'utf-8')
```

Then i tried to decrypt it

decrypted_key = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_key, None, None, None, 0)

And got exception:

```
pywintypes.error: (13, 'CryptProtectData', 'The data is invalid.')
```

and i cant figure out how to fix it

Also for the second part of encryption, it seems that i should use pycryptodome, something like this snippet:

```
cipher = AES.new(encrypted_key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt(data)
```

But i can't figure out where i should get nonce value

Can someone explain, how to do Chrome cookies decrypting correctly?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since Chrome version 80 and higher, cookies are encrypted using AES-256 in GCM mode. The applied key is encrypted using DPAPI. The details are described [here, section *Chrome v80.0 and higher*](https://xenarmor.com/how-to-recover-saved-passwords-google-chrome/).

The encrypted key starts with the ASCII encoding of `DPAPI` (i.e. `0x4450415049`) and is Base64 encoded, i.e. the key must first be Base64 decoded and the first 5 bytes must be removed. Afterwards a decryption with `win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData` is possible. The decryption returns a tuple whose second value contains the decrypted key:

```
import os
import json
import base64 
import win32crypt
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

path = r'%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State'
path = os.path.expandvars(path)
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    encrypted_key = json.loads(file.read())['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']
encrypted_key = base64.b64decode(encrypted_key)                                       # Base64 decoding
encrypted_key = encrypted_key[5:]                                                     # Remove DPAPI
decrypted_key = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]  # Decrypt key
```

The encryption of the cookies is performed with [AES-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) in [GCM mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). This is authenticated encryption, which guarantees confidentiality and authenticity/integrity. During encryption an authentication tag is generated, which is used for integrity verification during decryption. The GCM mode is based on the CTR mode and uses an IV (nonce). In addition to the 32 bytes key, the nonce and the authentication tag are required for decryption.

The encrypted data start with the ASCII encoding of `v10` (i.e. `0x763130`), followed by the 12 bytes nonce, the actual ciphertext and finally the 16 bytes authentication tag. The individual components can be separated as follows:

```
data = bytes.fromhex('763130...') # the encrypted cookie
nonce = data[3:3+12]
ciphertext = data[3+12:-16]
tag = data[-16:]
```

whereby `data` contains the encrypted data. The decryption itself is done using [PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#gcm-mode) with:

```
cipher = AES.new(decrypted_key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag) # the decrypted cookie
```

Note: Generally, there are also cookies stored that have been saved with Chrome versions below v80 and are therefore DPAPI encrypted. DPAPI encrypted cookies can be recognized by the fact that they start with the sequence `0x01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB`, [here](https://ired.team/offensive-security/credential-access-and-credential-dumping/reading-dpapi-encrypted-secrets-with-mimikatz-and-c++#protecting-and-unprotecting-data) and [here, section *About DPAPI*](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html). These cookies can of course not be decrypted as described above, but with the former procedure for DPAPI encrypted cookies. Tools to view cookies in unencrypted or encrypted form are [*ChromeCookiesView*](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html) or [*DB Browser for SQLite*](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), respectively.

Comment: Your solution is working, thank you very much! In my case I removed "data = bytes.fromhex('763130...') # the encrypted cookie" part, because encrypted cookie, recieved from sqlite3 cursor already was in bytes type

Comment: instead of `json.loads(file.read())`, you could simply just do `json.load(file)`

Comment: is there an alternative for linux?

Comment: @CenkTen - I don't know. You should post a question about this on SO if needed.

Comment: @CenkTen here's a Linux answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23727331/507721

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have copied the DPAPI encrypted key value from one user account on Windows and are trying to call CryptUnprotectData WinAPI while logged on as another user. This will not work, by nature of DPAPI.