# How does Visual Studio encrypt passwords in a .pubxml.user file?

Tags: visual-studio, encryption, passwords, visual-studio-2019, webdeploy

When you tell Visual Studio to save your password for a publish profile, it creates a `.pubxml.user` file next to your publish file looking something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TimeStampOfAssociatedLegacyPublishXmlFile />
    <EncryptedPassword>AQAAANC[...]</EncryptedPassword>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

How does Visual Studio actually encrypt the password in the `EncryptedPassword` element?  I'd like to decrypt it because I've forgotten my password... now it's just stored encrypted in this file!

Comment: A pure guess based on the beginning `AQAAANC`: Is the beginning `AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+` (which is the Base64 encoding of `0x01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB`)? Then they might be DPAPI encrypted. After Base64 decoding of the data, decryption should be possible with the C# class [`ProtectedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=netcore-3.1), more precisely with the method `ProtectedData.Unprotect` (see the linked documentation for an example). If no value is known for `s_aditionalEntropy`, I would try `null`.

Comment: @Topaco Please give this as an answer and I can award the bounty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The data are [DPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) encrypted. DPAPI encrypted data starts hexadecimal with the byte sequence `0x01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB` or Base64 encoded with `AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+`, [here](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dpapi_data_decryptor.html).

For decryption with C# the class [`ProtectedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=netcore-3.1) or more precisely the static method [`ProtectedData.Unprotect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.unprotect?view=netcore-3.1) can be used. If no value is known for the entropy `s_aditionalEntropy`, `null` should be tried. More information about this parameter can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20358).

If the encrypted data are Base64 encoded, they must be Base64 decoded before decryption:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

...
String encryptedDataB64 = "AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+...";
byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedDataB64); 

byte[] s_aditionalEntropy = null;
byte[] data = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedData, s_aditionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

A more detailed example can be found in the linked documentation. The decryption is not limited to .NET, but is also possible with other languages, provided that a corresponding DPAPI-wrapper exists, e.g. in Python with [`win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423699/9014097) or in Java with [Java DPAPI](http://jdpapi.sourceforge.net).

Here's a console program that gets the Unicode string representation of the decoded data:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsolePassDecrypter {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string encryptedPass = "AQAAANC[...]";
            var decryptedPassBytes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedPass), null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted pass: " + System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedPassBytes));
        }
    }
}
```