# Encrypt Cookie and save to Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, encryption, cookies, cryptography

I am currently working on a Node.js script, which logs me into a website and automatically opens the browser with me being logged in.
I have been trying to add a cookie (gathered from the login POST-request) to the "cookie" database of chrome, but I am failing at getting the encryption right.
The Stackoverflow thread, I came along regarding the encryption of Cookies was this one: [Chrome 80 how to decode cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416350/chrome-80-how-to-decode-cookies)
But that thread was about decrypting a cookie and not encrypting it.

```
function encryptCookie(cookie, key){
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(cookie);
    encrypted = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from('v10'), encrypted, cipher.final()]);
    console.log(`Encrypted: ${encrypted}`);
    return encrypted; 
}
```

As for the "key" I am using the decrypted Key from Local State. (I decrypted the key using a DPAPI module.) I know that the encrypted cookie always starts with v10 so i added it as a prefix, but the encrypted Cookie is still too short.

I know I could work with a webscraper or just safe my password on the page, but I wanted to interact with the cookie Database and HTTP-requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423699/9014097) the structure of the data is described as follows:

> The encrypted data start with the ASCII encoding of v10 (i.e.
> 0x763130), followed by the 12 bytes nonce, the actual ciphertext and
> finally the 16 bytes authentication tag.

I. e. the data is structured as follows:

- 3 bytes prefix v10
- 12 bytes IV
- ciphertext
- 16 bytes authentication tag

The length is: 3 + 12 + ciphertextlength + 16. Furthermore, since no padding is used in GCM mode, the length of the ciphertext is the same as that of the plaintext.

Among other things, the posted code uses a wrong IV length, does not concatenate the IV and does not take the authentication tag into account.

One possible implementation of encryption/decryption is:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function encryptCookie(cookie, key){
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
    const encryptedCookie = Buffer.concat(
      [
        Buffer.from('v10'),         // prefix
        iv,                         // 12 bytes nonce
        cipher.update(cookie),      // cookie data
        cipher.final(), 
        cipher.getAuthTag()         // 16 bytes authentication
      ]);
    return encryptedCookie; 
}

function decryptCookie(encryptedCookie, key){
    const prefix = encryptedCookie.slice(0, 3);                                     // prefix
    const iv = encryptedCookie.slice(3, 3 + 12);                                    // 12 bytes nonce
    const ciphertext = encryptedCookie.slice(3 + 12, encryptedCookie.length - 16);  // encrypted cookie
    const authTag = encryptedCookie.slice(encryptedCookie.length - 16);             // 12 bytes authentication tag
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);
    const decryptedCookie = Buffer.concat(
      [
        decipher.update(ciphertext),      // encrypted cookie
        decipher.final(), 
      ]);
    return decryptedCookie; 
}

// Encryption
const cookie = Buffer.from('The test cookie with some data');
const key = Buffer.from('01234567890123456789012345678901');
const encryptedCookie = encryptCookie(cookie, key);
console.log(encryptedCookie);
console.log(encryptedCookie.length);

// Decryption
const decryptedCookie = decryptCookie(encryptedCookie, key);
console.log(decryptedCookie.toString('utf8'));
```

For the sample cookie with a length of 30 bytes the encrypted data has a length of 3 + 12 + 30 + 16 = 61 bytes.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast and detailed answer! 
I will definitely try this the way you recommended it. I have never been encrypting/decrypting before, so thank you again for the help. I will comment on the post again once I have the time to work on this project (most likely in about 10 Hours).