# How to decrypt chrome cookies in python in linux

Tags: python, google-chrome, encryption, cookies, utf-8

I want to decrypt chrome cookies.
chromium version - 103.0.5060.53
I tried the code in this stackoverflow post: [Decrypting Chromium cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153159/decrypting-chromium-cookies/23727331#23727331)

my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
import sqlite3
# Function to get rid of padding
def clean(x): 
    return x[:-x[-1]].decode('utf8')

def get_encrypted_value():
    import sqlite3

    path = '/home/hasan/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/Cookies'
    db = sqlite3.connect(path)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE name = "cf_clearance";')
    ENCRYPTED_VALUE = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
    print(ENCRYPTED_VALUE)
    return ENCRYPTED_VALUE

# replace with your encrypted_value from sqlite3
encrypted_value = get_encrypted_value() 

# Trim off the 'v10' that Chrome/ium prepends
encrypted_value = encrypted_value[3:]

# Default values used by both Chrome and Chromium in OSX and Linux
salt = b'saltysalt'
iv = b' ' * 16
length = 16

# On Mac, replace MY_PASS with your password from Keychain
# On Linux, replace MY_PASS with 'peanuts'
my_pass = 'peanuts'
my_pass = my_pass.encode('utf8')

# 1003 on Mac, 1 on Linux
iterations = 1

key = PBKDF2(my_pass, salt, length, iterations)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_value)
print(clean(decrypted))
```

but I get this error:

```
b'v11J\xf6=Z\xe5\xef\x0f\xf6Wi\xcc\x80KL\xa3U\x06\xdag\xb5*\xbeS\x17\xbb\xa5\xa9\x0e\xa5\xdb}&\xfcJ\x03[\xc3:\x1d\x1c*\xfd\x1b\xf4\xa4\xbd\x93\xd0\xf2Y\xbe\x1ef\x87\r\xec\xb2g?\x84mi\xd6\x87'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hasan/test.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(clean(decrypted))
  File "/home/hasan/test.py", line 6, in clean
    return x[:-x[-1]].decode('utf8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Check [this](https://xenarmor.com/how-to-recover-saved-passwords-google-chrome/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423699/9014097).

Comment: did you solve this ?