# Expiring asp.net session cookie

Tags: asp.net

In my logout function, I have

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30);
```

I see that the response contains set-cookie for ASP.NET_SessionId with the proper expiration, but then the browser (Chrome in this case) never actually deletes the cookie.

Comment: possible duplice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tiy can try with this code

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId");
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```