# flask-login: Chrome ignoring cookie expiration?

Tags: python, web-applications, python-2.7, flask, flask-login

I've got the authentication working with flask-login, but it seems like no matter what I use for the cookie duration in flask, the session is still authenticated. Am I setting the config variables properly for flask-login? I've tried

```
app.REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION"] = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
```

Even if I close the browser, wait a while, and hit a url that should be protected, I can still access it. Is this related to [this issue with chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies). If I clear my cookies, I get the expected login page. All this makes me think that the cookie timeout is not being respected.

Also, what does `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` do in flask?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION` is used for "Remember me" functionality, that is, how long to remember logged in user even if he closed the browser.  The separate cookie is used for that, the name of which can be set by `REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME` (`remember_token` by default).  To force login session to expire after some time (even if the browser is still kept running), set `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` somewhere where you keep your app settings:

```
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

And in your login view set `session.permanent = True`:

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    # ...
    if login_user(user):
        session.permanent = True
        return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))
    # ...
```

Comment: So if session.permanent == False, Even "REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME" cookie expire,  login user information will be kept in the "SESSION_COOKIE_NAME" cookie's value and the "SESSION_COOKIE_NAME" cookie never expire, right?