# Avoid navigator to remember the session

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

Using Symfony2.0 and FOSUserBundle, how can I always avoid the "remember me" behavior on navigators?

As said in documentation, Remember me is disabled by default. And you have to set this in the configuration to make it work:

```
# app/config/security.yml
firewalls:
    main:
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

Well. I am NOT putting that configuration in security.yml. But, somehow, the navigator is ignoring my desires and it does keep the necessary cookies to re-take a previous valid session from some cookie.

How can I indeed make the user always to log in with his/her login and password?

Comment: So the session persists even when you close the browser and reopen the page?

Comment: Yes, that exactly is :(. Only using Chrome, though. But I don't wan't it to happen in any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are doomed when you want to force this on chrome users:

[Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies)

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/cjt3WwgOJ3c

Whenever the feature  "Continue where I left off" is actived you will probably have this behavior.