# Javascript cookies and redirect

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I need help changing this code so that the cookie only last through the session instead of 1 year forward. What changes do I need to make?

```
function createCookie(name,value,) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000*365));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }
```

I tried to do this, but it doesn't seem to work. Cookie is created but doesn't disappear after session closes.

```
function createCookie(name,value) {
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; path=/";
}
```

--- Update ---

I made some small changes to the code:

```
    function createCookie(name,value,expires) {
        var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }
```

Now I was using Chrome, and it didn't work with the code I had and it doesn't work with this code either. But this code works in IE, Firefox and Opera. The cookie is deleted when the session is over, but not in Chrome...

Comment: Just don't set the expires property or set it to `null`

Comment: ` document.cookie = name+";path=/"`

Comment: In regards to your chrome comment, chrome has a tendency to keep a session cookie between restarts, do some googling on it.

Comment: This is discouraging, looks like session cookies doesn't work properly in Chrome I take it? No way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome since the version 19 had made a breakthrough change regarding the handling of session cookie. In order to improve the user experience the session cookie will not be removed.

If I understood correctly, since the option set in chrome settings say: "Continue where I left off", the session cookie never expires.

Please look at:

[Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies)

Comment: Yeah I read...I can't understand this decision at all it seems crazy to me.

Comment: I'm trying to workaround with a custom javascript implementation. I'll update my answer when the solution will be ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome or Firefox then set expires to 0, if you are using IE then leave out the expires parameter all together.

Comment: No. Omit the expires completely. Setting it to 0 may delete the cookie