# RoR sessions in ubuntu's chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with sessions in ruby-on-rails.
It appears when using Chrome(27.0.1453.93) and Ubuntu 12.10.

Here is my code:

```
if remember == '1'
      cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    else
      session[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    end
```

I log in without 'remember', then I restart Chrome (on Ubuntu), and session data is not lost, meanwhile restarting Mozilla clears session data.

Could you explain what is happening here, please?

I want to have the same behavior in both browsers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Chrome is (incorrectly, from a security standpoint) not releasing the session cookie after closing.  See [Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies) for more info on this.  Note that if FireFox crashes and offers to 'restore the open sessions' for you, it will do a similar thing (again, incorrectly).  Other popular browsers don't appear to have this issue at this time.

This incorrect behavior isn't likely to be fixed anytime soon either - see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513