# how to check session expiration on ajax call functionality

Tags: jquery, ajax, session

I retrieve data on ajax call from database in mvc 4 project.I have to check session expiration on ajax call and I set timeout to 1 min..So I put following code in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someSessionVariable = '@Session["key"]';
    if(someSessionVariable == "")
        alert("Session expire");
    else
        alert("Session still exist");  
</script>
```

Even after 1 min. I get value in **someSessionVariable** variable and `Session still exist` alert message display.So how can I check session expiration in this condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Configure session expiration in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

timeout is in minutes

**UPDATE:**

If you are using **Chrome**, it stopped to  handle session cookie expiration some time ago. According to Chrome developers this should improve user experience

http://erlycoder.com/111/google-chrome-session-cookie-expiration-issue-feature-your-personal-data-is-insecure-now-

Chrome issue is marked as **WONTFIX**
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513

**Firefox** went this way too
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=443354

Also look at this answer [Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies)

Comment: actually I wasn't asking how to configure session in web.config file.
My question is how to track session exist or not on ajax call after timeout meet.I have to redirect user to login if session expire.

Comment: Ok I understand. Session expiration is handled by the browser, see an update