# Laravel 5 Auth logout not working

Tags: php, laravel

When I use the built-in Authentication and try to log the user out at `/auth/logout` - it does not work as hoped. It appears to keep the user logged in. But when I clear my browser cache, I can see that is has actually logged the user out.

I don't get any errors on the page nor errors in the log file.

I am guessing that `Session::flush()` at the logout method would possibly solve this - but I don't know where to put it.. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I was having the same issue, my mistake was put the middleware "guest" to the logout route. :/

Maybe you are having the same problem.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For anyone that has problems solving it with the accepted solution: I started with Laravel 5.1 and updated to 5.2. The following fix worked for me:

Try changing your 'logout' route to

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

or in AuthController constructor add

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
}
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34667356/1275778 (also check the other answers there if you're still having problems afterwards)

Comment: Thanks, your second option worked immediately after many other failed solutions!

Comment: This one worked for me, I'm using 5.2, thank you so much lorey.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Changing the default `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getLogout']]);` to `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);` did the trick.

Comment: I just changed the route `...@getLogout` to `...@logout` and everything works now. thanks

Comment: Worth mentioning: Watch out that your logout route is not part of a route group which implements `guest` middleware already. In that case it will ignore the above exception.

Comment: If anyone comes here in the future still not finding joy in the answers: should you be using Auth::logout() or auth()->logout() -- try running session()->flush AND session()->save after. Much Googling brought me to find that, and it works a charm!

Answer (score 13):

Try this..

Put In following code "**class AuthController extends Controller**"

```
public function getLogout()
    {
        $this->auth->logout();
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: I needed to change Session::flush(); to \Session::flush(); but otherwise worked for my situation.

Comment: @UmairHamid Put that code (use ``Auth::Logout()`` instead of ``$this->auth->logout();``) into a new function (say, ``public function logout()``) in the AuthController and point your route for auth/logout there.

Comment: Tried with same but no result at al

Comment: Also no luck here; but @lorey's suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. 
The problem was actually a simple little error in the configuration of the route and controller.

You see the route actually specifies a method of `getLogout` and the controller exception is looking for `logout`.

The only thing you need to do is change the exception in the controller. No need for any additional methods. The `getLogout` method already exists and works perfectly.

Here is the actual code

#### app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

#### app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

The `_construct` method should look like that:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

Comment: This works.  It seems weird you have to do this considering that `getLogout` is the method called in `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` so they should have `getLogout` be default in the `AuthController.php`.

Answer (score 4):

this ocurrs because the middleware is called for every route. you can add a exception to " logout route" in App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (!$request->is('/logout') && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For logout in laravel 5.6 and later version :

use in your view page:

```
    <a href="{{ url('logout') }}">Logout</a>
```

use this in your web.php

```
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

Comment: why is it you have to override the default get route?

Comment: By default Laravel uses post method for logout, We convert this to get. Using this override. Have your any confusion ?

Comment: It makes sense on what you are saying, just wondering why it comes as a post out of the box.

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for this for ages - why do we have to request the default post request with a get request though - this confuses me, why can we not just post with blade directly to the default Auth::logout.

Comment: You can use default login, but that is not get method, that is post request;

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with updated laravel 5.2. I have used laravel's auth controller and I solved this problem using like,

`/logout` instead of `/auth/logout` same for `/register` and `/login` in instead of using `/auth/register` and `/auth/login`.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.2 the url is a little different ...

Use this

```
php artisan make:auth
```

This will generate the routes for auth and some templates for login e register...

Be careful to use this with existing projects, it can make changes to your code

Answer (score 1):

Not enough on browsers that recover your tabs after crash ([Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies)) . Also, after redirect a new session is created. Solution: in AuthController, as mentioned above, in getLogout, set a variable and pass it to redirect:

```
$data['logout'] = true;
return redirect('/')->with('data',$data);
```

In your home view do this:

```
@if(session()->has('data') && session('data')['logout'])
{{session_unset()}}    
{{setcookie('laravel_session', "", -1, "/")}}
@endif
```

I believe Laravel redirect reinitialises Session. So after redirect, in view, reset delete cookie. Anybody can comment on this? Is this the right reason this works?

Answer (score 0):

To log out a user with Laravel using the built in authentication tools, it is as simple as using `Auth::logout();`.

Please also check the various session settings in `config/session.php` if the sessions behaves unpredictably.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very very simple

in Http->Middleware->Authenticate.php change "login" in else statement to "/"

return redirect()->guest('/');

and define following route in routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});
```

for logout call following function:
    public function getlogout(){
        \Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/home');
    }
***this is important*** redirect to "/home" instead of "/" that first calls $this->middleware('auth');
and then in middleware redirect to "/"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Laravel 5.3. To fix it, I noticed that the traits used in

`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController`

are outdated, so I changed the line

`use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;`

into

`use AuthenticatesUsers`;

and also the line in the constructor

`$this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);`

into

`$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);`

Then the method `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout` started to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In 5.4 this worked for me...

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>

<form id="logout-form" action="/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">{{ csrf_field() }}</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in case no any solutions is working try this
for multiple custom guards if you use `auth()->logout` then it wont work
just use `auth('your-guard-name')->logout();` then it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

It is a quite old thread but finally I found a simple trick to log the user out from the server:

```
return Auth::logout();
```