# Laravel 5.2: Auth::logout() is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I'm building a very simple app in Laravel 5.2, but when using `AuthController`'s action to log out, it just simply doesn't work. I have a nav bar which checks for `Auth::check()` and it doesn't change after calling the log out action.

I have this route inside the routes.php file:

`Route::get('users/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');`

and it's outside the

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function ()` statement.

I did also try to add the follow action at the end of the AuthController.php file.

```
public function getLogout() 
{
    $this->auth->logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

If I clear Google's Chrome cache, it works.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? Could you explain in details what action do you run and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Hello @MarcinNabiałek. I edited the question. I hope it's better explained.

Comment: Your logout route should not be outside the `web` middleware group. It should be inside it.

Comment: @ThomasKim still doesn't work

Comment: what does `Auth::logout()` do? is it bring the same result? although it should bring the same result. anyway, could you post entire `AuthController` code?

Comment: If anyone comes here in the future still not finding joy in the answers: should you be using Auth::logout() or auth()->logout() -- try running session()->flush AND session()->save after. Much Googling brought me to find that, and it works a charm!

Answer (score 38):

I also had similar problem in Laravel 5.2. You should change your route to

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

or in AuthController constructor add

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this later and if it works, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Aztecnologic This fixed *my* issue. Don't know why we have to write a custom logout method in Laravel 5.2 though—I didn't have to in 5.1. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem, too. Any explanation why? Seems to be linked to updating from 5.1 to 5.2 while using the old laravel/laravel boilerplate repository.

Comment: In addition to above answer,
You can customize redirection after logging out by adding below code in AuthController
protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'auth/login';

Comment: Adding `getLogout` to the `except` array did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

use below code

```
Auth::logout();
```

or

```
auth()->logout();
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is from the 'guest' middleware in the AuthController constructor. It should be changed from `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);` to `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);`

If you check the kernel file, you can see that your guest middleware point to `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class`

This middleware checks if the user is authenticated and redirects the user to the root page if authenticated but lets the user carry out an action if not authenticated. By using `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);` , the middleware will not be applied when the getLogout function is called, thereby making it possible for authenticated users to make use of it.

N/B: As in the original answer, you can change `getLogout` to `logout` since the getLogout method simply returns the logout method in laravel's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

In `Http->Middleware->Authenticate.php` change `login` in else statement to `/`

```
return redirect()->guest('/');
```

and define following route in routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});
```

for logout call following function:

```
public function getlogout(){
    \Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

***Important:*** redirect to `/home` instead of `/` that first calls `$this->middleware('auth');` and then in middleware redirect to `/`

Answer (score 1):

This should be the content of your constructor in AuthController

```
$this->middleware('web');
$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in `routes.php` file `Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');` 
and add this in your view 
`<a href="{{ url('/auth/logout') }}" > Logout </a>` 
it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below route and do not add this inside any route group(middleware):

```
Route::get('your-route', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

Now logout should work as it should in L 5.2 without modifying anything in `AuthController`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('/');
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}
```