# Laravel 5.2 - Using Auth::check() not working in MIddleware

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-5

I am trying to make a middleware for different type of users in my Laravel 5.2 app.
So, what is I am doing is making different middlewares for different users.

As far as I am knowing Auth::check() will not work without musing middleware web from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479994/laravel-5-2-authlogout-is-not-working).

So, what I have done is-

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','admin']], function ()
{
    //suspend, activate, delete
    Route::get('users', [
        'uses'          => 'AdminController@users',
        'as'            => 'users'
    ]);

    //Edit,activate,suspend, delete
    Route::get('articles', [
        'uses'          => 'AdminController@articles',
        'as'            => 'articles'
    ]);
});
```

**AdminMiddleware.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            return "asd";
            //return Auth::user();
            //return redirect('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('login');
        }

        //now return the valid request
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'          => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'admin'         => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    'user'          => \App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware::class,
    'auth.basic'    => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest'         => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle'      => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

**AdminController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function users()
    {
        return view('admin.users');
    }

    public function articles()
    {
        return view('admin.articles');
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error-

[image]

when "**return Auth::user();**" called inside middleware, "return Auth::user();" is working in other place (view and controllers) but not working like old versions of Laravel.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: why are you trying to return the user model from a middleware ?

Comment: Actually I want to know user type in my middleware so that I can decide anything to do with that, so as for testing I am trying to return everything.

Comment: just `dd` what you want to check, dont return them. What are you trying to check on the 'user' model ?

Comment: user_type - in user model

Comment: Actually the problem is not what I am returning, problem is I am not allowed to do Auth::check()

Comment: you can and its is done in other middlewares

Comment: Comment VerifyCsrfToken line in Kernel.php and check.

Comment: in middleware, you can not use else, simply after the end if body writes return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could potentially do something like this, adjust where needed

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    if (! $user || $user->user_type != 'admin') {
        return redirect('login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

The error you are receiving is coming from the fact that you are not returning a `Response` object from your middleware. The `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware is trying to add a cookie to the response it gets from passing the request down the pipeline. In this case it is not getting a `Response` object but instead a string or `User` because a string or `User` was returned in your middleware.

Comment: works fine for me on 5.2. seems to be a problem with the stack you have because there isn't a proper response object being passed back through the pipeline, but again, returning text or a user object from your middleware isn't going to help you, it is just going to break things.

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Cowboy and @lagbox ,
Thanks for trying to help, unfortunately they were not working, but I have solved it.

I have solved it by running-

> php artisan cache:clear
>
> composer dump-autoload
>
> php artisan clear-compiled
>
> php artisan optimize

and then middleware-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            if(strcmp( "admin" , Auth::user()->user_type ) != 0 )
                return redirect('home');
            else
                return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('login');
        }

        //now return the valid request
        //return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And Route-

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','admin']], function ()
{
    //suspend, activate, delete
    Route::get('users', [
        'uses'          => 'AdminController@users',
        'as'            => 'users'
    ]);

    //Edit,activate,suspend, delete
    Route::get('articles', [
        'uses'          => 'AdminController@articles',
        'as'            => 'articles'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added routes in web group as well so make sure your kernel file should have following middleware group.

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

The error due to session. make sure your kernel file contains session middlewares.

Comment: the OP already has the web middleware group applied. if they didn't they wouldn't be getting the error coming from the csrf middleware, which is provided by the web group.

Answer (score -1):

I've the same issue. In my case, I'm facing this in Multiple authentication. If you're using Multiple authentications or even single authentication with different primary key name in the table instead of `id`, This may cause.

In Laravel, the default primary key for the users table is `id`. In case, you've changed that into `user_id` or something, You have to mention that in your Model. If not, Laravel can't create the session for the user as a result, the `Auth::attempt()` will work fine but `Auth::check()` will not. So, Make sure you've mentioned that inside the model class.

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
   $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```