# Laravel 5.0 logout is redirecting back to home

Tags: laravel

My laravel version is 5.0.35 and my issue is that when I go for a logout it redirects back to home page.

After hours of self research and googling, I have gone through many resolutions but none worked.
Eg: $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);

The guest middleware is redirecting the request back to the home page for some reason, don't know why it is exempting the logout method even when it is added to do so.
Anyone please help me resolve this.

My AuthController now

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar  $registrar
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');  //****** Change to your desired link.
    }
}
```

I have upgraded the project to 5.1.0 in a hope to resolve the issue, but still no use.
Anyone please help.

Comment: what do you wanna do?

Answer (score 1):

Modify this:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;


class AuthController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar  $registrar
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
        $this->auth->logout();
        return redirect('/mypage'); //**your link
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a LoginController there, this is version 5.0.35. If you mean the AuthController, I have checked by adding these, but didn't worked.

Comment: Show your controller.

Comment: I have updated the question with my authcontroller including the method you gave me. Please check.

Comment: Modified the answer. Check now.

Comment: Tried, but still the same issue. I guess I have tried this once yesterday itself. The request is getting handled by the guest middleware and redirecting back, that's what happening.

Comment: Try that $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']); again.

Comment: Tried $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout','getLogout']]);
as well, not working. :(

Comment: do php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:cache

Comment: Still not working. This is one hell mess I have ever come across.

Comment: Show your route list, in cmd php artisan route:list

Comment: Try changing your middleware to $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);

Comment: Both logout and getlogout? Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747530/laravel-5-auth-logout-not-working

Comment: Yeah, both. I have already gone through that thread and tried those, but didn't worked.