# session_set_cookie_params(0) not working in Google Chrome

Tags: php, session-cookies

I add this code for close browser destroy session.

This code works fine Mozilla, Opera but doesn't work in Chrome.

I also set `session.cookie_lifetime = 0` in php.ini file.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);  
session_set_cookie_params(0);

session_start();
```

Comment: you must either access it via IP  `127.0.0.1`  or set the cookie domain parameter to the empty string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change sequence of session

```
session_start(); 
session_set_cookie_params(0);
```

Comment: This effectively uses the default cookie settings. Using session_set_cookie_params() after session_start() is a no-op. -1 for usefulness.