# Delete cookie on browser close not on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I seen many post regarding same problem but i am not getting exact solution. i want to delete cookie on browser or tab close event using javascript. I have made delete cookie function and called on **onbeforeunload** event. But i seen that event also called when page refresh i dont want to delete cookie on page refresh. And i seen in many post that they are detecting link click, keypress event of F5 and form submit and in that they preventing **onbeforeunload** event. But then what about refresh button click and press enter at url bar. So i think this is not a exact solution. so help me out from this problem.

Further information is i am creating cookie using PHP and want to delete this cookie on browser close.

Comment: There is no "browser close", nor "page refresh" event. `onbeforeunload` event fires on **both** page (tab) close and page refresh.

Comment: @hindmost so no solution for browser close cookie delete?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 12):

Cookies are automatically deleted when the browser is closed, unless you specify a lifetime for the cookie.

Comment: you mean i will set cookie without expiry time??

Comment: Yes exactly. Without expiry time, the cookies are deleted on browser close.

Comment: i am setting cookie using below code $cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day*/ can you tell me how to set this cookie without expiry time

Comment: What jquery cookies plugin are you using?

Comment: I am not using any plugin for this i have made following function for delete cookie function delete_cookie( name, path, domain ) {
                       
                          document.cookie = name + "=" +
                            ((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+
                            ((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
                            ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
                        
                      }

Comment: Simply remove the ``expires`` value from the function

Comment: they are called session cookies

Comment: Suppose I do close the browser but just close that particular browser "tab", will the cookie for the application of that tab be deleted? Will this behavior be browser specific?

Comment: I'm leaving out the expire date and the cookie isn't set at all, I've tested this in both newest Firefox and Safari and it's the same behaviour ...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer true. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the cookies when browser close uses the following code

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {    
    var cookies = $.cookie();
      for(var cookie in cookies) {
        $.removeCookie(cookie);
      }
    return true;
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: this event is firing when page refresh i dont want to perform delete cookie function on page refresh....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a cookie on browser close, better would be to check if cookie exists on page load and delete that.

Comment: my concept is i am saving product id in cookie when i am saving product as my favourite product without login and i want to delete this cookie on close browser not on page refresh your solution will delete my cookie on page refresh also.