# Session cookie not expiring When Chrome Browser is closed on smart phones

Tags: android, iphone, google-chrome, session, cookies

I have an application that sets a session cookie during the begin request of an application. The expectation is that this clears out when the browser is closed and it is working as designed for most scenarios except when browsing using Chrome on Android device or an iPhone.

Looks like a Smartphone version of Chrome doesn't clear off session cookies...

Did anyone encounter this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome on the desktop has the same problem. It doesn't kill session cookies because it keeps a process running in the background. Assume it's the same 'feature'

Comment: I have chrome 40.x.x.x version on my desktop and it doesn't display this behavior. On my laptop with 43.x.x.x , I could reproduce the scenario, do you know if this was introduced recently?

Comment: No, it's been around a while. Check Settings -> Advanced -> System -> Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed. Also, see this related SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10772420/31299