# Check if beforeunload is caused by closed tab/window or refresh

Tags: javascript, events, cookies, browser, window

I am trying to bypass chromes ["Continue from where you left off" session cookie issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies), where cookies are not destroyed after closing browser window / tab.

To do this I have added an `beforeunload` listener to the window, that fires a function to remove a cookie:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', destroySession)
```

However this also destroys a cookie when I refresh the page or click on "go back" buttons in the browser, so I need sub sequential checks in my `destroySession` function to see what caused `beforeunload` to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - You can't.

The long answer is - You can setup a convoluted way of "detecting" a refresh vs being opened in a clean tab or window BUT (there is always a but) note that is is not perfect and each method comes with it's own set of issues (I HIGHLY DO NOT recommend using them): [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)