# How to make a session last longer?

Tags: session, elixir, phoenix-framework

I use this to create a session for a user:

```
put_session(conn, :user_id, user_id)
```

but it expires quite fast, in about a day I think. I want it be around  2 weeks. How can I specify a time frame within which it's valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default session cookies do not have an expiry date set, which creates a session cookie that exists [until the user closes the browsing session](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33692/what-typically-is-the-expiration-date-of-a-session-cookie). You can set a specific duration by passing `max_age: <integer>` to the `plug Plug.Session` call in `lib/my_app/endpoint.ex`:

Change:

```
plug Plug.Session,
  store: :cookie,
  key: "_my_app_key",
  signing_salt: "..."
```

to:

```
plug Plug.Session,
  store: :cookie,
  key: "_my_app_key",
  signing_salt: "...",
  max_age: 2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 # number of seconds in 2 weeks
```

You can verify this by inspecting the `set-cookie` headers from your app. They'll turn from:

```
$ curl -I localhost:4000 | grep set-cookie
```

> set-cookie: _my_app_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAANmb29GP-MM4khcFDg.V3iUo5xw9HqgCmvRLBvhRguMixOlzZH_pqxRIYVAwdQ; path=/; HttpOnly

to:

```
$ curl -I localhost:4000 | grep set-cookie
```

> set-cookie: _my_app_key=SFMyNTY.g3QAAAABbQAAAANmb29GP-M66RqWt64.6PvtX96B9jwgyIhjJBX5AiDV9_96838plEpgGxS9u0Q; path=/; expires=Thu, 23 Mar 2017 15:06:48 GMT; max-age=1209600; HttpOnly

Comment: actually no, I close my browser, then open it and  it's still alive.

Comment: @Junidi That's because for example Chrome doesn't kill your session after restarts, you gotta change the settings for that I believe

Comment: Yep, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies.

Comment: @JustMichael, I didn't say Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You are putting it into a session which has limited flexibility. You can create a separate cookie, as one way to go and set its `max_age` like this:

```
put_resp_cookie(conn, :user_id, user_id, max_age: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: so every will be able to edit their cookie and login on behalf on other user?!!

Comment: @Junidi That's just the way how to handle this situation, handling the security issues is off the question.