# how can i cookies clear when i close the chrome browser

Tags: .net, vb.net

i want to cookie clear when i close the chrome browser.

explorer browser is no problem, but chrome browser is problem.

i close chrome browser, i open chrome browser and go site. still alive..

i need to your advice, please tell me.

thank you.

```
'### cookie create logic (log in process)
<NonAction()>
Sub setCookies()
   Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("mysitename")
   aCookie.Domain = "mysitename.com"
   aCookie("userid") = "aaa"
   aCookie.Path = "/"
   aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(600)
   Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
End Sub


'### cookie clear logic (log out process)
<NonAction()>
Sub clearCookies()
   Response.Cookies("mysitename").Domain = "mysitename.com"
   Response.Cookies("mysitename").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags. This is not C#.

Comment: i'm sorry, and thank you.

Comment: [This can be caused by having Chrome set to Continue where you left off.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772420/1115360)