# Google Chrome on android does not delete session cookies

Tags: android, google-chrome, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

We have used ASP.NET Core identity to do login and remember me functionality. It's working fine on most of the browsers but on mobile chrome it has issues.

So if you select the remember me on login then it will save a cookie for a 1 month and that is the functionality but when you don't select remember me checkbox on on login screen it creates a session cookie instead of an authentication cookie and it should be deleted by chrome when we close the chrome browser instance but it's not being deleted by chrome.

After researching a lot I have found that in the desktop version on startup there is a feature given by chrome that you can start from where you left off. See below link

[Chrome doesn't delete session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies)

So if you select the new tab option then it would work fine. I have tried to find a similar option on the Android Chrome browser but I am not able to find it.

So, Is there a way to disable session cookies in the android chrome browser to delete session cookies when the browser is closed?

Any help would be really appreciated.