# How to delete cookie from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete cookie on clicking sign out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079565/delete-cookie-on-clicking-sign-out)

I want to delete cookies when the user logout.

Here is my code:

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["currentUser"] != null)
 {
     DeleteCookie(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["currentUser"]);
 }


       public void DeleteCookie(HttpCookie httpCookie)
        {
            try
            {
                httpCookie.Value = null;
                httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20);
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I believe that you shouldn't clear the `Value`. AFAIK, that's how the cookie is identified.

Comment: Note that deleting the cookie is only a secondary cleanup. The important part is invalidating the value of the cookie on the server side.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
 HttpCookie currentUserCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["currentUser"];
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("currentUser");
 currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
 currentUserCookie.Value = null;
 HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie);
```

It works.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but for newcomers, I don't think removing the cookie first does anything useful, since it is set again later anyhow.

Comment: I can confirm what @JamesWilkins said. The ```Remove``` is not needed since the cookie is overwritten.

Comment: According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.setcookie?view=netframework-4.8 you should use HttpContext.Current.Response.Set instead of HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie not sure about the difference though.

Comment: I found that I needed to have the Remove line - otherwise I had a lot of expired cookies of the same name lingering around, and when it came time to read the value, one of the old "expired" incarnations was being read

Answer (score 20):

Instead of adding the cookie, you should change the `Response's` cookies `Expires` to a value in the past:

```
if (Request.Cookies["currentUser"] != null)
{
    Response.Cookies["currentUser"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);   
}
```

Sidenote: Instead of `throw ex` you should just `throw` it to keep its stacktrace. [C#: Throwing Custom Exception Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761216/c-throwing-custom-exception-best-practices/4761295#4761295)

Comment: Why catch the exception anyway if nothing is done with it?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Still I can see the user name after logout.  httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

Comment: @Dykam: You can decide later to log it or do whatever you want. I often add a `TODO: implement logging` there in the first version. On this way you have at least added the try/catch to remember that this might cause an exception.

Comment: What if I want to delete a cookie, then create an other cookie with the same name? Will the Expires act on my new created cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Add the cookie (with past expiration) to the HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies collection instead.  Request is for reading the cookies the server was sent - response is for sending cookies back to the client.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can make use of Response.Cookies.Clear() or Response.Cookies.Remove().

Comment: Sorry...i did a quick search and found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx

May be this might be useful to u.

Comment: As you can see in my question, I already set the cookie's expiration time to past. But the same result.