# How to delete or expire cookie in Chrome using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is one of those dumb questions. The answer should be simple, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Anyone have any ideas where else for me to look for some rep?

I'm adding a cookie on a button click

```
var impersonationCookie = new HttpCookie("UserImp_ImpAuid");
impersonationCookie.Value = Encode64(auidToImpersonate);
impersonationCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
impersonationCookie.Path = "/";
Page.Response.Cookies.Add(impersonationCookie);
```

I'm expiring a cookie and clearing the value on a `page_load`

```
HttpCookie currentUserCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserImp_ImpAuid"];
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("UserImp_ImpAuid");
currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
currentUserCookie.Value = null;
HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie);
```

Chrome (v 69) still shows the cookie with the value `MDAwMDM5OTk2` and with an expiration date of `When the browsing session ends`.

[image]

I've tried plenty of variations from other questions

- [Delete a cookie on signing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079565/delete-cookie-on-clicking-sign-out)
- [How to delete a cookie from .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116511/how-to-delete-cookie-from-net)
- [How to delete cookies on an asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635349/how-to-delete-cookies-on-an-asp-net-website)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies

Comment: did you tried on different browser?

Comment: @mjwills - Appreciate the recommendation, but didn't seem to work.  I think I've tried this before as well.

Comment: @Girish No I hadn't tried another browser. Tried Firefox just now and it looks like it worked no problem.  And thanks for the link on the explanation.  Makes sense.  If you wanted to put this as the answer I'll confirm/accept Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, This could be because chrome setting "Continue where you left off".

You can cross check in a different browser.

[Chrome Doesn't Delete Session Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies)

Comment: if this is the case, any idea why the expiry date and value haven't been udpated?  I would expect Chrome to at least reflect that the expiration date has changed and the value to be cleared out.